# Is there a more efficient way to rotate images in Java than AffineTransform?

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage

I've looked around for ways to rotate `BufferedImage`s in Java and all I have found is `AffineTransform`. That's fine, but it seems like a bit of overkill if all I want to do is rotate 90 degrees. Would it be more efficient to just do it pixel-by-pixel? Is there some other method I could use?

Comment: Is there a *performance problem*?

Comment: @user2864740 I'm just now starting a new project that will involve rotating a lot of images. I want to make sure there isn't any lag in the future.

Comment: Hide the transformation in in a `rotateImage90` method. If/when there is a problem, re-explore the implementation; and be prepared to run performance tests. (There are also some duplicate'ish questions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Javadoc of the class you mention:

> Handling 90-Degree Rotations
>
> In some variations of the rotate methods in the AffineTransform class, a double-precision argument specifies the angle of rotation in radians. These methods have special handling for rotations of approximately 90 degrees (including multiples such as 180, 270, and 360 degrees), so that the common case of quadrant rotation is handled more efficiently.

That makes it seem like you shouldn't worry about performance without solid proof to the contrary.

In addition take note of the following method: [`quadrantRotate(int numQuadrants)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#quadrantRotate(int))

Comment: That sounds great. Is there an equivalent method for reflecting over the X or Y axis? I looked in the documentation, but didn't see anything.

Comment: Just apply a -1 scaling factor on one of the axes, for example with [getScaleInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getScaleInstance(double,%20double)).